# PowerShell script to run application (with commands)

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to run an application from C:\Program Files\APP\app.exe with the application built in commands. When I run from the command prompt, I can get the result I wanted. But I would like to use the script which will check other components of servers along with this one to avoid running this command manually. I tried both of the mentioned scripts below & I am not getting any output. It just opens a command prompt window, runs the result, and closes the command prompt,but I would like to get the output in an output file. Any suggestions? Please let me know.

```
$Output = "C:\Information.txt"
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\APP\app.exe" -ArgumentList "query mgmtclass" | Out-File $Output
```

Additionally, I also tried -

```
$Output = "C:\Information.txt"
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\APP\app.exe" -PipelineVariable "query mgmtclass" | Out-File $Output
```

I was also thinking that I can write a batch file & get output written in the temp directory & get those output using the command mentioned below -

```
Get-Content -Path 'C:\Program Files\tivoli\tsm\baclient\dsmerror.log' | select-object -last 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using the `RedirectStandardOutput` parameter instead of `| Out-File`:

```
$Output = "C:\Information.txt"
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\APP\app.exe" -PipelineVariable "query mgmtclass" -RedirectStandardOutput $Output
```

Update:

The error you are getting ("Missing an argument") means exactly what it says. I can't see the line of code you ran to get the error, but I can replicate by omitting the value of `RedirectStandardOutput`. This example uses splatting so the line of code is not so long, and you can see more clearly what `RedirectStandardOutput` is:

```
$Output = "C:\Information.txt"
@{
   FilePath = "C:\Program Files\APP\app.exe"
   PipelineVariable = "query mgmtclass"
   RedirectStandardOutput = $Output
} | % { Start-Process @_ }
```

Comment: Hi ST8Z6FR57ABE6A8RE9UF...pls let me know if you have update...I mentioned the error I am getting in my previous post.